# Documents & Data is larger than it should be for my app

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a filter app and I am letting users to capture new photo or select a photo from library with UIImagePickerController using SwiftUI.

I noticed that my app size is greater than it should be. My app size is 12mb but Documents & Data size is 600 mb.

I do not use cache or store any photo to userdefaults. But I couldnt find how to release that storage.

Is there a debug that I can follow and find out what is taking that much space? Or any ideas how I can reduce the Documents & Data size?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you find why ?